# Checking if package.json dependencies match the installed dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a way to check if the dependencies installed in `node_modules` match the dependencies listed in the `package.json` / `package-lock.json`?

I know I can type `npm install` to update. But how can I check if I need to type `npm install`.

Ideally I'd like to add that to my build script. You can imagine something like

```
#!/bin/sh
npm install --check-only
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo continue with build
else
    echo you need to "npm install" the latest deps
fi
```

Either shell out to npm or call some official npm API but I didn't see either.

Maybe such an option is hiding in plain sight and I'm just not seeing it.
I did find a 3rd party solution but given `npm install` already has to do this to know whether or not it needs to install something I'd much prefer a way to do it via the official `npm` so that if `npm` changes it's criteria for updating I'll continue to get the same result.

Is there a way to check if the dependencies listed in the package.json/package-long.json match what's installed?

Comment: seems is what the [check-dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-dependencies) package is doing

Comment: @EricWong, my understanding is that check-dependencies will only check if top-level packages have upgrades available. It is meant for checking if your package.json needs to be changed. It's not for checking if dependencies can be upgraded within the constraints defined in your package.json.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `--dry-run` flag. According to the docs `man npm-install`:

> The  --dry-run  argument  will report in the usual way what the install would have
>          done without actually installing anything.

You can run this command, check the output. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the return value changes depending on whether there are any changes, but you can parse the output.

If the last line of the output looks like:

```
up to date in 7.064s
```

Then you are good, but if it looks like:

```
added 1 package in 7.014s
```

or

```
updated 1 package in 6.019s
```

Then an `npm i` is required.